# htaccess and friendly urls with more than one parameter

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, friendly-url

I have no experience working with htaccess, so i have this url: index.php?id=1163&sub=hp
i have managed to convert the first portion into a friendly url with htaccess:

www.mytesturl.com/index.php?id=1163 into www.mytesturl.com/computers/
however i need to convert the whole url (two parameters) for example:
www.mytesturl.com/index.php?id=1163&sub=hp into www.mytesturl.com/computers/hp/

here is my htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?perf=$1
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mytesturl.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mytesturl.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

can someone please point me into the right direction? the second instruction should be on the same line or its necesary to add another rule or directive
similar to:     RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mytesturl.com/$1 [R=301,L]

Answer (score 0):

You can possibly use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?perf=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?perf=$1&sub=$2 [L,QSA]
```

But remember your rules are using `?perf=...` as first parameter not `?id=...` as your question says.